# adding keys to an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, data-structures, mapping

I am looking for a solution to add additional keys to an object.

```
array = [{A: 5, B:10, C: 20},{A: 3, B: 2, C: 5}];
```

In the next step i will calculate a new_value:

```
array.forEach((element) => {
 let new_value = ((element.A + element.B) / element.C;
```

Now, i have to add the result to each object in the above mentioned array:

```
array = array.map(element => new_value);
```

The outcome should be:

```
array = [{A: 5, B:10, C: 20, new_value: 0.75},{A: 3, B: 2, C: 5, new_value: 1.2}];
```

Unfortunately that´s not the case! How can I add the calculated value to the object?

Comment: Already the second code example comes with a(n at least two times) broken syntax. How should the audience know whether it sees just a fraction of the OP's code or indeed a broken script? If at all utilizing `forEach` the code should look close to ... `array.forEach(element => element.new_value = ((element.A + element.B) / element.C));`... which of cause mutates each item of `array` thus the latter as well.

Comment: Regarding the so far provided answers, are there any questions left?

Comment: How do you get `new_value: 1.2`?

Comment: @user14155947 ... Regarding the provided answers, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

From my above comments ...

> *"Already the second code example comes with a(n at least two times) broken syntax. How should the audience know whether it sees just a fraction of the OP's code or indeed a broken script? If at all utilizing `forEach` the code should look close to ... `array.forEach(element => element.new_value = ((element.A + element.B) / element.C));` ... which of cause mutates each item of array thus the latter as well."*

```js
const array = [
  { A: 5, B: 10, C: 20 },
  { A: 3, B: 2, C: 5 },
];

const newArray = array
  // - `map`ping should never mutate the original `array`.
  .map(({ A, B, C }) => ({
    A, B, C, new_value: (A + B) / C
  }));

console.log({ array, newArray });

array
  // - with `forEach` one usually would mutate
  //   each of an operated array's item.
  .forEach(item =>
    item.new_value = (item.A + item.B) / item.C
  );

console.log({ array });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
const 
      array = [{A: 5, B:10, C: 20},{A: 3, B: 2, C: 5}];
      
      array.forEach(({A,B,C},i) => array[i].new_value = (A + B)/C);
      
console.log( array );
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple enough

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let array = [{A: 5, B:10, C: 20},{A: 3, B: 2, C: 5}];
    array.forEach( element => {
        element.D = (element.A+element.B)/element.C;
      }
    );
    console.log(array);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
7:04:19 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:04:19 AM  Info    [ { A: 5, B: 10, C: 20, D: 0.75 }, { A: 3, B: 2, C: 5, D: 1 } ]
7:04:20 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```